# How to pprint custom collection

Tags: python, abc, pprint

I am not able to simulate pprint on my custom collections.
See the following behaviour:

```py
>>>from pprint import *
>>>pprint(["x"*80]*4)
['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
```

However, when I pprint my custom `abc.Sequence` object:

```py
import collections

class MySequence(collections.abc.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.elements = list(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.elements)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self.elements

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.elements.__getitem__(index)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.elements)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.elements.__repr__()
```

I get the following:

```py
>>>pprint(MySequence(["x" * 80]*4))
['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
```

At the end I need to print my dataclass using my custom class getting nice indentation:

```py
@dataclass
class MyClass1:
    halloffame: List = field(default_factory=lambda: ["x" * 80]*4)

@dataclass
class MyClass2:
    halloffame: MySequence = field(default_factory=lambda: MySequence(["x" * 80]*4))
```

So the following classes should print the same, however, I get:

```py
pprint(MyClass1())
MyClass1(halloffame=['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'])
pprint(MyClass2())
MyClass2(halloffame=['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'])
```

Comment: Any reason for not implementing `__repr__` (and `__str__`) in a more useful way?

Comment: The `pprint` module (and the `PrettyPrinter` class it is based on) doesn't have hooks for defining what it means to pretty-print values of arbitrary classes.

Comment: @DeepSpace I tried multiple ways, but didn't find a correct one. The example is just to ilustrate the issue for the question.

Answer (score 1):

`pprint` won't format the class for you it only converts it to a string using the `__repr__` method.

You can use [`pprint.pformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) in the `__repr__` method:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "MySequence(\n" + pformat(self.elements) + "\n)"
```

Comment: It works on a parent object, but indentation does not happen when it is a dataclass member. In classes with more members still looks a bit wierd.